# ORO CRM unable to create unique keys

Tags: php, orocrm, orocommerce

orocrm 5.0, ubuntu server arm64, installed with composer & symfony

I'm trying to create a unique key in Account entity with a custom field "domain" with the web UI, but this error in logs appear :

```
[2022-02-25T17:31:17.246271+00:00] request.INFO: Matched route "oro_entityextend_entity_unique_key". {"route":"oro_entityextend_entity_unique_key","route_parameters":{"_route":"oro_entityextend_entity_unique_key","id":"79","_controller":"Oro\\Bundle\\EntityExtendBundle\\Controller\\ConfigEntityGridController::uniqueAction"},"request_uri":"https://orocrm.webmore.fr:8000/entity/extend/entity/unique-key/79","method":"POST"} []
[2022-02-25T17:31:17.375084+00:00] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Exception\EntityConfigValidationException: "Invalid entity config for "Oro\Bundle\AccountBundle\Entity\Account": Unrecognized option "unique_key" under "entity". Available options are "contact_information", "description", "entity_alias", "entity_plural_alias", "grid_all_view_label", "icon", "label", "plural_label"." at /home/ubuntu/crm/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/EntityConfigBundle/EntityConfig/ConfigurationHandler.php line 128 {"exception":"[object] (Oro\\Bundle\\EntityConfigBundle\\Exception\\EntityConfigValidationException(code: 0): Invalid entity config for \"Oro\\Bundle\\AccountBundle\\Entity\\Account\": Unrecognized option \"unique_key\" under \"entity\". Available options are \"contact_information\", \"description\", \"entity_alias\", \"entity_plural_alias\", \"grid_all_view_label\", \"icon\", \"label\", \"plural_label\". at /home/ubuntu/crm/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/EntityConfigBundle/EntityConfig/ConfigurationHandler.php:128)"} []
```

I've tried with a `custom` entity (also created with the web UI) and same result.

Someone can explain the problem here ?

Thanks.

Comment: It says in the error Unrecognized option "unique_key" under "entity". 
 
Available options are "contact_information", "description", "entity_alias", "entity_plural_alias", "grid_all_view_label", "icon", "label", "plural_label"." 

Maybe thats wrong entity or you need to add that rule in to that entity to create one ?

Comment: I don't get it, i'm using the dashboard to add unique key, so i'm expecting to do it easily, do i need to write custom Account entity rules into a specific file ?